# C program compiled on Windows gives varied output

Tags: c, windows

I was getting suspicious that it wasn't just my code, and I couldn't figure out why my code's output was so varied. It would sometimes print some lines, and other times, it wouldn't print anything.

Thinking it was something weird, I started ripping code from [here](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_5:Exercise_13), and sure enough, I'm still getting this weird unexpected behavior where the program doesn't always print.

I took an example from the K&R C book. It's the exercise where you're trying to mimic tail. However, when I compile the code below and run it, the output varies, even though I've used the same input each time.
I ran this code specifically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINES        1024
#define MAXINPUT        10240
#define DEF_NUM_LINES   10

int  getlines   (char *);
void parse_args (int, char **);

char  linestr[MAXINPUT];
char *lineptr[MAXLINES];

int num_of_lines = DEF_NUM_LINES;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int lines;
        int ltp = 0;
        int i; int c;

        *lineptr = linestr;

        /* Parse the argument strings passed to the program */
        if (argc > 1) {
                parse_args(argc, argv);
        }

        /* Get the input from the user */
        lines = getlines(linestr);

        if (num_of_lines == 0) {
                num_of_lines = 10;
        }

        ltp = lines < num_of_lines ? lines : num_of_lines;
        printf ("\n>>> Printing %d line(s):\n", ltp);
        if (ltp == DEF_NUM_LINES) {
                printf (">>> The default number of lines to print is ");
                printf ("%d\n", DEF_NUM_LINES);
        }
        printf ("\n");

        for (i = lines; i > 0; i--) {
                while ((c = *lineptr[0]++) != '\n') {
                        if (i <= ltp) {
                                printf ("%c", c);
                        }
                }
                if (c == '\n' && i <= ltp) {
                        printf ("\n");
                }
        }

        return 0;
}

int getlines (char *buffer)
{
        int i, count = 0;
        char c;

        for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && i < MAXINPUT; i++) {
                *buffer++ = c;
                if (c == '\n') {
                        lineptr[++count] = buffer;
                }

        }
        *buffer++ = '\0';

        return count;
}

void parse_args (int argc, char **argv)
{
        char c;

        while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-') {
                c = *++argv[0];
                switch (c) {
                case 'n':
                        num_of_lines = atoi(*(argv + 1));
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

[image: Odd output for tail]

In the first two instances of running it, the output is the same, but it's not correct. It doesn't print the number of that should have been printed on line 40, and it looks like the program just stopped executing.

Then running it a third time, it didn't even print those lines that were printed in the first two instances of running the program!

I've also used the same input, and received different output than the examples in the picture! In another instance, the program actually output some (but not all) of the lines.

How can the output differ so much? It's so puzzling how in one instance of running the program, it'll print some of the lines, and in other instances, it won't. Does it have something to do with powershell/cmd's output and not the code? I really have no clue.

I'm currently using Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt to compile this code. Any ideas as to why the program sometimes prints lines, and other times it doesn't? My initial guess is that it has something to do with Windows because I've wrestled with the Windows Console Handles in the past.

EDIT:
This was embarrassing. In short, once I sorted everything out, I finally figured out the problem. The keymapping on my keyboard was changed and so Ctrl-Z was really Ctrl-C, which explained why my output varied.

Comment: It is not working right? And hard to debug? And apparently hard to read. Get rid of the statements making it even worse, such as `*++argv[0]` as the very first step.

Comment: How did you break inputting lines?

Comment: No clue. I've now tried it on two different windows machines using 3 different versions of the program (all three versions were ripped from the link above). I assume that if they were on that site, they'd work. I also assumed that they wouldn't all suffer from the same problem of having the output differ like I'm having. Which is why I think it's a problem with windows/the compiler that I'm using, and not the code.

Comment: Try writing input to a text file and call `tail3 -n 4 < tail.txt`. The program works for me (linux and win7 cmd)

Comment: What exactly is your input? 1<Enter>2<Enter>3<Enter>...<Ctrl+Z><Enter>. <Enter> meaning press Enter key and <Ctrl+Z> meaning press Ctrl+Z keys.

Comment: So using IO redirection like that works. I hadn't tried that. I was running the program straight from the command line, and just typing 1-10 on a new line, and then entering EOF.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, that it exactly what I was doing. However, as I just commented above, doing ".\tail3.exe -n 4 < tail.txt" or ".\tail3.exe < tail.txt" prints the correct output, where "tail.txt" contains "1\n2\n\3...\n10\n". So the code works, I'm just still left wondering why the input from the console yields such wild results.

Comment: Strange that <Ctrl+Z> isn't echoed. If I do it I see `^Z` on the screen

Comment: Here on my Windows 10 it works as expected from a cmd console but it does not work as exepected from a powershell console, apparently it has something to do with powershell.

Comment: ... wait, now it works also in powershell (?!) very strange. Put this at the beginning of the program to be sure that argc and argv are what you expect: `printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
`

Comment: Yeah, it is odd. Thanks for all of your help Jabberwocky and Ingo Leonhardt. I really appreciate ya'll taking the time to look into it. It seems to also work for me in cmd, but not Powershell.

Comment: Please try what I've suggested in my last comment and tell us what the output is using powershell, I'm somewhat curious.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, there's no such thing as a CMD console or PowerShell console. They both use a regular Windows console (conhost.exe). Possibly the console mode flags could be different for you or the OP. I compiled this using Visual C++ 19.11, and it worked fine when run in the console in Windows 10.0.17134 -- from CMD and PoweShell there's no difference. It won't work in PowerShell ISE, but that's not the console and not designed for interactive console apps.

Comment: Yeah, argc and argv are what I expect them to be. It's just that, later on during the execution, it skips print lines, ends early, or it prints some, and then just exits randomly.

Comment: @eryksun yes, maybe I used the wrong terms.

Comment: @RobertStefanic indeed very strange, try to printf the values returned by `getchar`

Comment: @Jabberwocky That works as expected. I think eryksun was onto something where we could possibly be launching PS in different modes.

Comment: Are you using any programs that modify the behavior of the console, such as conemu or ansicon? Try running the executable directly from Explorer. Add a final `getchar()` before exiting to prevent the console window from immediately closing.

Comment: Not to my knowledge; however, I just tried your suggestion for running it from explorer and adding `getchar()` to the end of main, and it worked perfectly fine. I had initially thought the problem was the compiler/Windows, but now it's looking like it's a problem with my environment.